# Install Launch4j in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

It may sound silly, I downloaded [Launch4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/latest/download?source=files) but I don't know how to install it. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the latest version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/), currently version [3.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/latest/download?source=files)
2. Open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and go into your Download folder, eg

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
3. Extract the archive

   ```
   sudo tar xf launch4j-3.8-linux.tgz -C /opt
   ```
4. Create desktop file

   ```
   nano /usr/share/applications/launch4j.desktop
   ```

   and add the lines below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Launch4j 
   Comment=Launch4j Executable Wrapper
   Icon=launch4j
   Exec=/opt/launch4j/launch4j
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=Launch4j
   ```
5. Start via your Launcher

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have downloaded Launch4j...just once again make sure you downloaded linux file

Just sharing you the link if not downloaded the same...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.8/launch4j-3.8-linux.tgz/download

Step 1 : Go to the Download Folder and extract the launch4j-3.8-linux.tgz

Step 2 : Now open terminal

Step 3 : Go to the directory where you Extracted the file(Using "cd" command)

Step 4 : Once you are in the Directory of extracted file
you just need to run the jar file there

run the command : java -jar launch4j.jar