# launch4j in ubuntu

Tags: java, files

I finished my first program in Java, and I want to convert it to an .exe file to make it runnable in Windows, so I downloaded Launch4j to convert jar files to exe files. I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604998/install-launch4j-in-ubuntu-14-04), but when I click on the launch4j icon nothing happened, so I used `java -jar launch4j.jar` instead, but I got this error.

[image: the error]